# How to \enddocument inside an environment

Tags: environments, conditionals

I have a document of the form

```
\begin{document}
some text
\begin{myenv}
....
\end{myenv}
some other stuff
\end\document
```

I would like to set a boolean `\newif\if@test` in the header to control the output, such that if I set `\@testtrue`, the document would end just after `\end{myenv}` and not display *some other stuff*. My attempt is to put

```
\if@test \enddocument
```

at the end of the declaration of `myenv`. But this does not work, LaTeX complains that `begin{myenv}` is ended by `\enddocument`  ...

How could I do that?

Comment: I think that if it is an environment that is nested this is going to be a problem.

Comment: Related but not a duplicate: [Calling `\end{document}` in a macro](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24292/calling-enddocument-in-a-macro)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple solution is to use `\stop` to stop further compilation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{myenv}{}{\stop}
\begin{document}
some text
\begin{myenv}
Some other text
\end{myenv}
some other stuff
\end{document}
```

This is a TeX command redefined in LaTeX `ltmiscen.dtx`.

Comment: Indeed, `\stop` is the way to go here. For a further example see [Ulrike's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22999/2975) to one of my questions which introduced me to this nice macro.

Comment: this is definitly the simple solution i was looking for !

Answer (score 3):

To comment some phrases of your document I recommend the package comment.

On the other hand I recommend the package `etoolbox` with the hook `\AfterEndEnvironment`.

Here an example:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{myenv:enddocument}
\booltrue{myenv:enddocument}
\AfterEndEnvironment{myenv}{%
\ifbool{myenv:enddocument}%
  {\def\tempa{\end{document}}}%
  {\let\tempa\relax}%
  \tempa%
}
\newenvironment{myenv}%
{\par\noindent}%
{\par}
\begin{document}

some text
\begin{myenv}
....
\end{myenv}
some other stuff
\end{document}
```

Comment: to comment part of my text, i usually use either a command `\comm` defined by `{}` or an environment defined with `\NewEnviron{comm}{}`. Thanks for the interesting `\AfterEndEnvironment`

Comment: `\ifbool{myenv:enddocument}{\end{document}}{}`

Answer (score 2):

The following works due to the minimal grouping within your environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{myenv}{Start}{Finish}% \begin{myenv}...\end{myenv}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@test% New condition \@test<true><false>
\@testtrue% \@testfalse
\g@addto@macro{\myenv}
  {\if@test\g@addto@macro{\endmyenv}{\aftergroup\enddocument}\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
some text
\begin{myenv}
   ...
\end{myenv}
some other stuff
\end{document}​
```

`\g@addto@macro` works similar to [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\appto` command. `\aftergroup` waits for the current group to finish before executing `\enddocument`.

Comment: yes, but i don'T want to have the boolean test in `myenv`, but in the header.

Comment: @nicolasroy: I've updated my answer to accommodate for this, adding the test condition to the start of the environment `\myenv`.